# Filter Data to match a list of keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, data-structures

I have some code that will filter data to match a specified set of keys. So far, my code handles whether the data passed in is an array or an object of a specific kind. For example, a car object or an array of car objects, and the key list would be car attributes. However, I've just gotten a new dataset and I'm wondering the best way to go about handling it. Here is my code so far (don't worry too much about my array/object validation, I have custom functions that do much more checking)

```
const goodDataObject = {
  "make": "toyota",
  "model": "rav4",
  "color": "white"
  "mileage": "10000",
  "engine": "hybrid"
};

const goodDataArray = [
  {
    "make": "toyota",
    "model": "rav4",
    "color": "white"
    "mileage": "10000",
    "engine": "hybrid"
  },
  {
    "make": "chevrolet",
    "model": "cruze",
    "color": "black"
    "mileage": "20000",
    "engine": "gas"
  }
]

const badDataObject = {
  "dealer": "John Does Cars",
  "factory": "Michigan",
  "cars": [
    {
      "make": "toyota",
      "model": "rav4",
      "color": "white"
      "mileage": "10000",
      "engine": "hybrid"
    },
    {
      "make": "chevrolet",
      "model": "cruze",
      "color": "black"
      "mileage": "20000",
      "engine": "gas"
    }
  ]
}


// -->> results from goodDataObject:
{
  "make": "toyota",
  "model": "rav4"
}


// -->> results from goodDataArray:
[
  {
    "make": "toyota",
    "model": "rav4"
  },
  {
    "make": "chevrolet",
    "model": "cruze"
  }
]


// -->> results I WANT from badDataObject:
{
  "dealer": "John Does Cars",
  "factory": "Michigan",
  "cars": [
    {
      "make": "toyota",
      "model": "rav4"
    },
    {
      "make": "chevrolet",
      "model": "cruze"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my current code called with keys `["make", "model"]`.

```
function filterData(data, keys) {
  let filtered = null;
  
  if (typeof data === 'object') {
    for (let x of keys) {
      filtered[x] = data[x]
    }
  } else if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    filtered = [];
    for (let y of data) {
      let filteredObject = {};
      for (let key of keys) {
        filteredObject[key] = y[key];
      }
      filtered.push(filteredObject);
    }
  }
  return filtered;
}
```

I need to handle the badDataObject, and I've been thinking of a recursive option, but that has not been successful so far so I can't post much there

**Update: The keys are examples, but I have to handle all. Also, the badDataObject is an example. `cars` could be `vans` or `trucks` etc.**

Comment: How do you distinguish between `dealer`, which you don't handle, and `cars`, which you do?  What if the `dealer` property was an object with a `model` child?  Also, could the objects you want to project be nested arbitrarily deeply?  If so, how do you decide at what levels to do the projection?

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy to do using `Array.map()`.

I've updated the function, so now it also takes an object that describes what data you want.

```js
const badDataObject = {
  "dealer": "John Does Cars",
  "factory": "Michigan",
  "cars": [{
      "make": "toyota",
      "model": "rav4",
      "color": "white",
      "mileage": "10000",
      "engine": "hybrid"
    },
    {
      "make": "chevrolet",
      "model": "cruze",
      "color": "black",
      "mileage": "20000",
      "engine": "gas"
    }
  ]
};

function goodDataObject(data, target) {
  for (const prop in target){
    data[prop] = data[prop].reduce((acc, item) => {
      const obj = {};
      for(const key of target[prop]){
        if(key in item) obj[key] = item[key];
      }
      acc.push(obj);
      return acc;
    }, []);
  }
  return data;
}

console.log(goodDataObject(
  badDataObject, 
  { cars: [ "model", "make"]}
))
```

Comment: I've updated to mention that my keys and badDataObject are examples. I need to handle all possible keys and cars is just an example. Sorry for not being clear

Comment: @johnny_mac I've updated the code, so you can choose the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that badDataObject is going to contain the key 'cars', then you should just filter by extracting that key only.

Otherwise you can write a recursive function that determines whether  any key has the data(array or object) that contains desired keys but I think that would be an overkill and difficult to manage.

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirements aren't quite clear, as I mentioned in the comments.  But taking a guess at them, we can write something that looks for sub-objects that have the key properties we're looking for, and then keep only those, retaining everything where any of those keys is missing.  It might look like this:

```js
const map = (fn) => (o) => 
  Array .isArray (o)
    ? o .map (fn)
    : Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => [k, fn (v)]))

const select = (ks) => (o) => 
  Object (o) === o
    ? ks .every (k => k in o)
      ? Object .fromEntries (ks .map (k => [k, o [k]]))
      : map (select (ks)) (o)
    : o

const goodDataObject = {make: "toyota", model: "rav4", color: "white", mileage: "10000", engine: "hybrid"}
const goodDataArray = [{make: "toyota", model: "rav4", color: "white", mileage: "10000", engine: "hybrid"}, {make: "chevrolet", model: "cruze", color: "black", mileage: "20000", engine: "gas"}]
const badDataObject = {dealer: "John Does Cars", factory: "Michigan", cars: [{make: "toyota", model: "rav4", color: "white", mileage: "10000", engine: "hybrid"}, {make: "chevrolet", model: "cruze", color: "black", mileage: "20000", engine: "gas"}]}

console .log ('goodDataObject:', select (['make', 'model']) (goodDataObject))
console .log ('goodDataArray:', select (['make', 'model']) (goodDataArray))
console .log ('badDataObject:', select (['make', 'model']) (badDataObject))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here `map` is a helper function that calls `Array.prototype.map` for arrays and does something fairly equivalent for objects.  (`map (n => n ** 2) ({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})` returns `{a: 1, b: 4, c: 9}`.)

Our main function, `select` takes an array of target keys and returns a function that takes an object, tests whether it has all the target keys.  If they're not there, it recurs into its children.  If they are, it extracts just those keys.  And if it's not an object at all, it returns it intact.

You can see the behavior on a more complex object such as this:

```js
{
  company: "Acme Corp", 
  office: "Chicago", 
  companyCars: [
    {make: "toyota", model: "rav4", color: "white", mileage: "10000", engine: "hybrid"}, 
    {make: "chevrolet", model: "cruze", color: "black", mileage: "20000", engine: "gas"}
  ],
  departments: {
    marketing: {
      director: 'Susan',
      car: {make: "dodge", model: "neon", color: "red", mileage: "10000", engine: "gas"}, 
    },
    sales: {
      local: {
        manager: 'Peter',
        fleet: [
          {make: "toyota", model: "rav4", color: "blue", mileage: "30000", engine: "hybrid"}, 
          {make: "chevrolet", model: "cruze", color: "green", mileage: "50000", engine: "gas"}
        ]
      },
      state: {
        manager: 'Edmond'
      },
      national: {
        manager: 'Lucy',
        marketingVehicle:  {make: "Prevost", model: "X3-45", engineHours: "900", paintjob: "purple logo"}, 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It will return this:

```js
{
  company: "Acme Corp",
  office: "Chicago",
  companyCars: [
    {make: "toyota", model: "rav4"},
    {make: "chevrolet", model: "cruze"}
  ],
  departments: {
    marketing: {
      director: "Susan",
      car: {make: "dodge", model: "neon"}
    },
    sales: {
      local: {
        manager: "Peter",
        fleet: [
          {make: "toyota", model: "rav4"},
          {make: "chevrolet", model: "cruze"}
        ]
      },
      state: {
        manager: "Edmond"
      },
      national: {
        manager: "Lucy",
        marketingVehicle: {make: "Prevost", model: "X3-45"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```